# CSS Overlay - Fade in from bottom

Tags: html, css

I've got a grid with multiple boxes inside. Each box has got an overlay, with a heading and some paragraphs. The overlay is positioned below the box, just the heading is visible (bottom: ~-90%).

On mouseover the overlay moves up, until it's completely visible (bottom: 0). The text is aligned to the bottom of the box.

As you can see in the example below (full page), I have some issues with the dynamic height of the paragraphs.

Do you have any idea, how to solve this problem?

```css
.grid-item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;

  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  
  margin-right: 30px;

  background: #009345;
}
.grid-item:hover .item-overlay{
  bottom: 0;
}

.item-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  
  bottom: -30%;
  
  padding: 1rem;
  
  color: #ededed;
  transition: bottom .5s ease-in-out;
}
.item-title {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="item-overlay">
      <h2 class="item-title">Visible Headline 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Claudii libidini, qui tum erat summo ne
        imperio, dederetur.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="item-overlay">
      <h2 class="item-title">Visible Headline 2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Claudii libidini, qui tum erat summo ne
        imperio, dederetur. Conclusum est enim contra Cyrenaicos satis acute, nihil ad Epicurum. Quibus ego
        vehementer assentior. Bonum patria: miserum exilium.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot see any problem. Working fine here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can position the overlay **completely** out of sight (`top:100%`) and then pull the overlay back up again a designated value (say 4em) with a `transform:translate`.

The on `:hover` you increase the translation value to **-100%** (which equals the overlays own height) meaning the overlay will now sit right at the bottom of the parent div.

Switch the transtion to `transform` rather than `bottom`.

```css
.grid-item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  background: #009345;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.grid-item:hover .item-overlay {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
.item-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  transform: translateY(-4em);
  color: #ededed;
  transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
}
.item-title {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="item-overlay">
      <h2 class="item-title">Visible Headline 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Claudii libidini, qui tum erat summo ne imperio, dederetur.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="item-overlay">
      <h2 class="item-title">Visible Headline 2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Claudii libidini, qui tum erat summo ne imperio, dederetur. Conclusum est enim contra Cyrenaicos satis acute, nihil ad Epicurum. Quibus ego vehementer assentior. Bonum patria: miserum exilium.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```